# jQuery selecionando o próprio elemento

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-select2

Bom sou novo em jQuery e estou com um problema, como eu faço para selecionar o próprio elemento e não oque esta dentro dele, segue código:

```js
$('#add_phone').bind('click', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += $('[camp=phone]').find('input');

  $('#add_phone_div').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div camp="phone">
  <input type="text" name="phone[]" data-inputmask='"mask": "(99) 9 9999-9999"' data-mask>
</div>
<div id="add_phone_div"></div>
<hr/>
<button id="add_phone">ADD CONTATO EXTRA</button>
```

Oque eu pretendo fazer é pegar o HTML do input copia-lo e colar dentro da div de id="add_phone_div"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#add_phone').bind('click', function() {
  const $input = $('[camp=phone]').find('input');
  const $clone = $input.clone();

  $('#add_phone_div').append($clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div camp="phone">
  <input type="text" name="phone[]" data-inputmask='"mask": "(99) 9 9999-9999"' data-mask>
</div>
<div id="add_phone_div"></div>
<hr/>
<button id="add_phone">ADD CONTATO EXTRA</button>
```

Após obter o `input`, utilize o método `clone()` do próprio JQuery para gerar literalmente um clone do elemento em si, restando apenas inserir o elemento clonado como parâmetro do método `append`.

Comment: Nossa eu não conhecia o ´clone()´ do jQuery, me ajudou muito, obrigado!

Comment: O JQuery possui vários métodos que salvam o nosso código! Dê nada @Anorak!

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode fazer algo desse tipo:

```
$(function () {
    var clone = $("[name='phone[]']").html();
    $(document).on('click', '#add_phone', addPhone);

    function addPhone() {
        $('#add_phone_div').append(clone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Caso não funcione, substitua o ```.append``` para ```.html(clone)```

Comment: Usando $("[name='phone[]']").html(); ele não seleciona o elemento.

Comment: Bom, tenho uma dúvida, esse seu input será apenas 1, ou você fará outros com o mesmo nome ? Se for apenas 1, voce pode atribuir um id no mesmo e seleciona-lo através do ID. Com isso, ele copia o HTML do mesmo, ou você pode simplesmente clona-lo